# Schoolboy error with Flask Forms?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to build a GUI using Flask WTF. I followed a video online and copied the code EXACTLY. But when I navigate to http://127.0.0.1:5000/form I get:

" ValueError: View function did not return a response"

...plus the following traceback.

- File "C:\Users\jpetrie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1997, in **call**
- return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
- File "C:\Users\jpetrie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
- response = self.handle_exception(e)
- File "C:\Users\jpetrie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
- reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
- File "C:\Users\jpetrie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
- raise value
- File "C:\Users\jpetrie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
- response = self.full_dispatch_request()
- File "C:\Users\jpetrie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
- return self.finalize_request(rv)
- File "C:\Users\jpetrie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1630, in finalize_request
- response = self.make_response(rv)
- File "C:\Users\jpetrie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1725, in make_response
- raise ValueError('View function did not return a response')

Since I checked the scripts were the same as the video (many times) I dont think it is the code. All the imported packages are installed.

I think this is a schoolboy error to do with how I have set this up .  I cant figure out what is wrong. Please can someone help me out? I am using atom as a text editor for the first time (I used to use IDLE). I am not using virtualenv or anything.  (would that be an issue?) The .py and .html files are in the same local folder.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'Thisisasecret!'

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
  username = StringField('username')
  password = PasswordField('password')

@app.route('/form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def form():
  form = LoginForm()
  if form.validate_on_submit():
  return render_template('form.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

...AND HERE IS THE html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Form!</title>
</head>
  <body>
    <h1>Our form will be here OMG!</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('form') }}">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        {{ form.username }}
        {{ form.password }}
    </form>
    </body>
```

EDIT - I am struggling to see how this is a duplicate question and deserves a downvote, given that the reported error is (or appears to be) completely different. I looked at the "duplicate" and to me it doesn't look anything like my question.  This was not a "lazy" post. I spent a long time trying to figure this out and I also looked for similar questions. #Harsh

Comment: I edited the end of my original post to protest against the downvote.

Answer (score 2):

Your form() method does not return template in all cases. You have If statement that returns form.html only in particular case. Make this function return view in all scenarios. And format your code with 4 spaces before nested in if statement:

```
if not form.validate_on_submit():
   return render_template('form.html', form=form)

return render_template('home.html')
```

Comment: Thanks - that was a good call.  I removed the If statements entirely (for now) and then (having got ANOTHER error) figured out that form.html file must also be in a 'templates' folder.  I now have a successfully rendered template! Thanks for your help!